# Java Hazelcast Near Cache getting evicted very frequently

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have created the Hazelcast Config along with NearCache config as below:

```
 EvictionConfig evictionConfig = new EvictionConfig()
            .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.NONE)
            .setSize(1_000_000)
            .setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.ENTRY_COUNT);

    NearCacheConfig nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig().setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT)
            .setInvalidateOnChange(true)
            .setSerializeKeys(true)
            .setEvictionConfig(evictionConfig)
            .setCacheLocalEntries(true);
```

Further i have created the iMap using these config as

```
        config.getMapConfig(Constants.CacheNames.EMPLOYEE_CACHE).setReadBackupData(true).setNearCacheConfig(new NearCacheConfig(nearCacheConfig));
```

The issue what i am seeing is that even for small data 50 in number seeing lot of invalidation events for this iMap.

Not able to figure out what i am missing in this config.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the events by attaching a listener to IMap.

- If you call IMap#addLocalEntryListener() this will attach a listener for events on the **cluster member**
- If you call IMap#addEntryListener() this will attach a listener for events on the **whole cluster**

If you are doing like this and seeing evictions, those events are for the IMap not for NearCache.  There is no way to attach a listener to NearCache as far as I know.

Since you have **EvictionPolicy.NONE** and you have called **setSize()** the NearCache will cache the first 1_000_000 unique keys. Remember that for NearCache to work you  should call **IMap#get()**

You can check NearCacheStats like this

```java
LocalMapStats localMapStats = map.getLocalMapStats();
NearCacheStats nearCacheStats = localMapStats.getNearCacheStats();
```

When you check you should see **nearCacheStats.ownedEntryCount** <= 1_000_000
Dependes on how many get() calls you have made

If you have removed keys from IMap that exist in NearCache you may also see a non-zero value for **nearCacheStats.invalidations**

But you should see **nearCacheStats.evictions** as zero since you have disabled eviction for NearCache